# Find next largest number to given input with specific pattern

Tags: java, algorithm, math, numbers, pattern-matching

I am trying to solve a problem . Hoping for some help here.

Objective: Find a number which is immediate next to input and contains only 4 and 7 in it.

```
Input : 1234
Output: 4444

Input : 4476
output: 4477

Input  : 8327
Output : 44444
```

I am not looking for incrementing number and each time checking string characters for the pattern. That would be too slow for large numbers.

```
static String toOutput (int a) {
    // I am trying here all the possible other ways
}
```

Comment: How larger is your input? if your input less than 10^18 (long range), so only 2^18 numbers that contain only 4 and 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is fundamentally a manipulation of character strings, a plausible solution is to use string functions, particularly regular expressions. Here's a compact solution:

```
class Incrementer {
  Pattern p;
  public Incrementer() {
    p = Pattern.compile("(?:([47]*)([0-6]))?(.*)");
  }
  public String next(String s) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    m.lookingAt();
    return (m.group(1)==null
              ? '4'
              : m.group(1) + (m.group(2).charAt(0) >= '4' ? '7' : '4'))
           + m.group(3).replaceAll(".", "4");
  }
}
```

See it [here](http://ideone.com/aYRBtj).

(I'm not at all a Java programmer. Coding suggestions welcome.)

The regular expression matches the prefix of any sequence of legal digits (4 or 7) followed by an incrementable digit ( < 7). If that prefix is not matchable, the answer must be one digit longer, so it must start with the smallest legal digit (4). If the prefix is matchable, the prefix must be modified by bumping the last digit to the next legal digit. In both cases, all the digits following the (possibly empty) prefix are replaced with the smallest legal digit.

Of course, this could be done without actual regular expressions. The following essentially uses a state machine which implements the regular expression, so it might be faster. (Personally I find the regex version easier to verify, but YMMV):

```
public static String next(String s)
{
    int toinc = -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if (c < '7') {
            toinc = i;
            if (c != '4') break;
        } else if (c > '7') break;
    }
    char[] outChars;
    // Copy the prefix up to and including the character to be incremented
    if (toinc < 0) {
        outChars = new char[s.length() + 1];
    } else {
        outChars = new char[s.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < toinc; ++i)
            outChars[i] = s.charAt(i);
        // Increment the character to be incremented
        outChars[toinc] = s.charAt(toinc) >= '4' ? '7' : '4';
    }
    // Fill with 4's.
    for (int i = toinc + 1; i < outChars.length; ++i)
        outChars[i] = '4';
    return new String(outChars);
}
```

See it [here](http://ideone.com/NSwoOD).

Comment: This worked great. Let me check the execution time based on a test case executed in a loop with 5000 iteration.

Comment: This is taking more time than the accepted one. :( But of course it is more compacted.

Comment: @Javanator: Let me know how it works out. Perhaps a StringBuilder would have been better, but it would have been a lot of typing and I was going for the golf (short program), particularly since I can't code Java without a reference guide and it would have been even more methods to look up.

Comment: @Javanator: Also it probably would have been faster if the Incrementer class had only static members. Certainly, if you create a new Incrementer for every invocation, it's going to slow down a lot because every Incrementer has to compile the regex. So it would almost certainly have been faster to make `p` a static member. But you probably know a lot more about this stuff than I do.

Comment: @Javanator: OK, I hand-compiled the regex (with one capture group, which is actually sufficient), and got rid of most of the pythonisms. Maybe it's faster. Maybe it's easier to understand. Or maybe I should just stick to C++ and Python :)

Comment: Your solution suceeded by an average of 50Ms :)

Comment: This is awesome stuff! faster than mine solution! hats off to you!!

Answer (score 3):

Check this answer. Hope this helps :)

```
private static String toOutput(int n) {

    String input = String.valueOf(n+1);

    // create input character array and output character array of one more in size
    char[] inputChars = input.toCharArray();
    char[] outputChars = new char[inputChars.length + 1];

    boolean extra = false; //carry forward

    // traverse input array from last position to first position
    for (int i = inputChars.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        // for all other positions except last position check whether number is changed
        // (i.e. apart from 4 or 7), 
        // change all higher digits in output array to 4
        if ((i + 1) < inputChars.length) {
            if (inputChars[i] != '4' && inputChars[i] != '7') {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < inputChars.length; j++) {
                    outputChars[j + 1] = '4';
                }
            }
        }

        // if extra is true that means it is carry forward
        if (extra == true) {
            inputChars[i] = (char) ((int) inputChars[i] + 1);
        }

        // if input digit is less than equal to 4 output digit is 4 , extra is false
        if (inputChars[i] <= '4') {
            outputChars[i + 1] = '4';
            extra = false;

        } 
        // if input digit is between 4 to 7 output digit is 7 , extra is false
        else if (inputChars[i] <= '7') {
            outputChars[i + 1] = '7';
            extra = false;

        } 
        // if input digit is more than 7 output digit is 4 , extra is true 
        else {
            outputChars[i + 1] = '4';
            extra = true;
        }

    }

    // if carry forward is true, make extra digit to 4 otherwise it is not required
    if (extra == true) {
        outputChars[0] = '4';

    } else {
        outputChars[0] = ' ';
    }

    return new String(outputChars).trim();
}
```

Comment: Good answer, key is to keep track of carry

Answer (score 3):

```
static String toOutput (long a) {

    LinkedList<Long> q = new LinkedList<Long>();
    q.add(4L);
    q.add(7L);
    while(!q.isEmpty()){
        Long curr = q.pop();
        if(curr>a)
            return String.valueOf(curr);
        q.add(curr*10+4);
        q.add(curr*10+7);
    }
    return "";
}
```

This will solve the problem in close to O(LogN)

Comment: coolest and shortest answer till now. Lets see its time results on regression test cases.

Comment: Sorry, No where near to the selected answer for time case. A good attempt

Answer (score 1):

*

```
public class PatternTest {
    private static final char FOUR = '4';
    private static final char SEVEN = '7';
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String value = scanner.next();
        char startChar = value.charAt(0);
        Result result;
        if (startChar == FOUR || startChar == SEVEN) {
            result = getStartWith4Or7(value);
        } else {
            result = getNotStartWith4Or7(value);
        }
        System.out.println("Final value is : " + result.getValue());
    }
    private static Result getNotStartWith4Or7(String value) {
        Result result = new Result();
        char startChar = value.charAt(0);
        if (startChar < FOUR) {
            result.value = value.replaceAll(".", String.valueOf(FOUR));
        } else if (startChar > SEVEN) {
            result.value = value.replaceAll(".", String.valueOf(FOUR));
            result.flag = FOUR;
        } else if (startChar > FOUR && startChar < SEVEN) {
            result.value = getSubString(value).replaceAll(".", String.valueOf(FOUR));
            result.value = String.valueOf(SEVEN) + result.value;
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static Result getStartWith4Or7(String value) {
        Result result = new Result();
        if (value != null && !value.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
            char startChar = value.charAt(0);
            if (startChar == FOUR || startChar == SEVEN) {
                value = getSubString(value);
                result = getStartWith4Or7(value);
                result.value = getStartCharUpdate(startChar, result) + result.value;
            } else {
                result = getNotStartWith4Or7(value);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
    private static String getStartCharUpdate(char startChar, Result result) {
        String newValue = String.valueOf(startChar);
        if (result.flag == FOUR) {
            if (startChar == FOUR) {
                newValue = String.valueOf(SEVEN);
                result.flag = 0;
            } else {
                newValue = String.valueOf(FOUR);
            }
        }
        return newValue;
    }
    private static String getSubString(String value) {
        int len = value.length();
        String finalValue = "";
        if (len > 1) {
            finalValue = value.substring(1, len);
        }
        return finalValue;
    }
    static class Result {
        String value = "";
        char flag;
        public String getValue() {
            if (flag == FOUR) {
                value = FOUR + value;
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

*

Comment: Good work!! Easy to understand...getStartWith4Or7() has recursion which induces O(n) complexity.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be reading the digits right to left and check if that is less than 4 or 7 and add 4 or 7 respectively.

One optimization would be check if first(from left) digit is `>7` then its sure that you will have all `4's +`1 extra 4`.

You need to take extra care at the left most digit. If the left most digit is greater than `7` you need to add two 4s.

```
EX: 1234
right to left `4` is `4`
              `3` is `4`
              `2` is `4`
              `1` is `4`
```

This approach wont work if all the digits in the number are `4` or `7`. You need to have one condition and change one or two chars accordingly.

```
private static String toOutput(int a) {
        String s = Integer.toString(a);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (Integer.valueOf(s.charAt(0)) > 7) {
            for(int i=0; i<= s.length(); i++) {
                sb.append("4");
            }
            return sb.toString();
        }
        for(int i=s.length()-1; i>=0; i--) {
            Integer x = Integer.valueOf(i);

            if(x <=4) {
                sb.append(4);
            } else {
                sb.append(7);
            }
        }
        return sb.reverse().toString();
    }
```

This is not checking if the number has all 4's or 7's.

Comment: this didn't worked. Check for value 4576 - Output should be 4744

Comment: @Javanator, You are correct! will add cover that part, but it seems like it turns out to be like maveroid solution. I will fix it and the answer sometime over the weekend :)

Comment: if your answer worked and as i have other working answer. I will compute the execution time of different solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this.

```
 String num = "4476";
 double immediateVal = 0;
 int length = num.length();
 StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
 StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      sb1.append("4");
      sb2.append("7");
  }
 double valNum = Double.parseDouble(num);
 double val1 = Double.parseDouble(sb1.toString());
 double val2 = Double.parseDouble(sb2.toString());
  if (valNum < val1) {
     immediateVal = val1;
   } else if (val1 <= valNum && valNum < val2) {
      if(num.indexOf("4")==0){
         int firstIndexOf7=-1;
          for(int a=0;a<length;a++){
             firstIndexOf7=num.indexOf("7");
             if(firstIndexOf7!=-1){
                break;
              }
         }
        if(firstIndexOf7!=-1){
            StringBuilder sb3=new StringBuilder();
             for(int b=0;b<firstIndexOf7;b++){
                 sb3.append("4");
              }
             for(int b=firstIndexOf7;b<length;b++){
                 sb3.append("7");
              }
             immediateVal=Double.parseDouble(sb3.toString());
            }
       } else{
          immediateVal = val2;
       }
  }else if(valNum>=val2){
     immediateVal=Double.parseDouble(sb1.append("4").toString());
  }
  System.out.println(immediateVal);
```

Comment: This didnt worked. check for 4576. Your output is 4477.0 . Result should have been 4744

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to worry about performance for converting a number into a String.  You're evaluating a number as if it's a string, so it only makes sense to cast it to string to do the evaluation.

Something like this works and is reasonably fast.

```
  public static int closestNumber(int num) {
    for (int i = num + 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
      if ((i+"").matches("^[47]+$")) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Your number was too close to Integer's max value!");
  }
```

Ok, I wrote it using mod and no strings:

```
  public static int closestNumber(int num) {
    for (int i = num + 1; i < Integer.MAX_VALUE; i++) {
      if (containsOnly(i,4,7)) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Your number was too close to Integer's max value!");
  }

  public static boolean containsOnly(int evaluate, int numeralA, int numeralB) {
    while (evaluate > 0) {
      int digit = evaluate % 10;
      if (digit != numeralA && digit != numeralB) return false;
      evaluate = evaluate / 10;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: if your number is 123456789.. Imaging number of increments inside for loop

Comment: this is too costly operation and is not efficient as we are incrementing values and checking the characters for each value

Answer (score 0):

this can help you

```
static String toOutput(String input){
    char[] values = input.toCharArray();
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    int length = values.length;
    int currentPosition = 0;
    for(char current: values){
        Integer currentInt = new Integer(current);
        if(currentInt<4){
            //fill the string with 4, best result
            for(currentPosition;currentPosition<length;currentPosition++){
                result.append(4);
            }
            break;
        }
        else if(currentInt==4){
            result.append(4);
            currentPosition++;
            continue;
        }
        else if(currentInt<=7){
            result.append(7);
            currentPosition++;
            continue;
        }
        else if(currentInt>7){
            if(currentPosition=0){
               //fill the string with 4 but with length +1, best result
               for(currentPosition;currentPosition<=length;currentPosition++){
                    result.append(4);
               }
               break;
            }
            else{
               // you need work this case, change last 4 to 7 and fill the rest with 4. enjoy it.
            }
       }
    return result.toString();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like looking for the first digit that is not 4 or 7 counting from left to right.

Set up a index pointer to record the last index that hold digit "4" and check every digit from left to right.

1. Initial current pointer index (c) to -1 and set last "4" index (l) to -1
2. For every digit from left to right

   - update c (`c+=1`)
   - check digit value

     - `digit = 7` -> do nothing
     - `digit = 4` -> l = c
     - `digit < 4` -> this digit change to "4", all remaining digits sets to "4", end check
     - `4 < digit < 7` -> this digit change to "7", all remaining digits sets to "4", end check
     - `digit > 7` -> do necessary change and end check

       - `l = -1` => `444....444` `(no. of digit = n+1)`
       - `l > -1` => digit at l change to "7", all digits after l change to "4"

#### Idea

For a n-digit value, if it contains only "4" or "7", you do nothing.
Then, if there is any non "4" or "7", what should it be?

Analyzing the pattern, we need to know the first occurrence of non "4"/"7" digit (from left to right) only and all digits after the digit will change to "4" to minimize the value since `444...444 is the least k-digit value for combination of "4" and "7" for all k`.

1. Consider case `Xcccccccc` , `c` is any value

   - If `X in {4,7}`, consider case 2.
   - If `X in {1,2,3}`, the next value should be `444444444`.
   - If `X in {5,6}`, the next value should be `744444444`.
   - If `X in {8,9}`, the next value should be `4444444444`
2. Consider case `aaaaXcccc`, if `a` are "4" or "7"

   - If `X in {4,7}`, consider case `aaaaaXccc`.
   - If `X in {0,1,2,3}`, the next value should be `aaaa44444`.
   - If `X in {5,6}`, the next value should be `aaaa74444`.
   - If `X in {8,9}`, the next value should be `bbbb44444` or `bbbbb44444`.(b are "4" or "7")

     - then how to deduce `bbbb` or `bbbbb`?

       - if `aaaa does not have any "4"`, you get `bbbbb = 44444` (since aaaa=7777)
       - if `aaaa have "4"`, you get `bbbb` ("4" will be replaced by "7", e.g. 474779 => 477444)
3. Consider case `aaaaaaaaX`, this should be same as case 2 except no remaining digit need to be handle

Combine case 1-3, when the first occurrence of non "4"/"7" digit is in {8,9}, the difference in change of value depends on whether there is any "4" before the digit.